# Error in MVC view page displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an error in my MVC C# application. Although i am not getting following error in development environment, not even functionality is breaking, but when deploying it at IIS server, I am getting this error through elmah via emails with corresponding entry in the database

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DetailSmallForeignWidget(System.String, Int32, System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.String, System.String)' in 'BAR.Web.Controllers.ForeignRestaurantWidgetController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

After making `id` parameter nullable I got to know that the corresponding action method is getting called twice. Reviewing the code it looks fine but don't know why this is happening.

routes for the action method is as follows:

```
_routes.MapRoute(null, "widget/DetailWidget/{name}/{id}/{langID}/", 
    new { controller = "Widget", action = "DetailWidget" }, 
    new[] { "BAR.Web.Controllers" });
```

Function signature is as follows:

```
public override ActionResult DetailWidget(
    string name, 
    int id, 
    string refCode, 
    int? partySize,
    DateTime? when, 
    int? sittingTimeId, 
    string time, 
    string langID)

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/widget/IncludeWidget/Street/205/iframe/ja-JP" ></script>
```

Corresponding route

```
_routes.MapRoute(null, "widget/IncludeWidget/{name}/{id}/{mode}/{langID}/",
                 new { controller = "Widget",
                 action = "IncludeWidget" },
                 new[] { "BAR.Web.Controllers" });
```

Inside Includewidget func. code is something like below:

```
ContentResult content = new ContentResult();
string url = Url.ToAbsoluteUrl(string.Format("widget/DetailWidget/{0}/{1}/{2}", name, id.Value, langID), true);
content.Content = @"document.write('<iframe src=""" + url + @""" width=""300"" height=""430""  style=""border: none;"" frameborder=""0""></iframe>')";
content.ContentType = "text/javascript";
return content
```

I tried to rename the route parameters and tried to script references from the view page, but still it is showing the same error based on new parameter name. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You will have to show the code that is calling this controller action. If you are using AJAX please show the corresponding javascript file. If you are not using AJAX please show the corresponding view.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/widget/IncludeWidget/Street/205/iframe/ja-JP" ></script>

Comment: Alright, and now you expect me guessing what's inside this ja-JP script? Or maybe you will update your question and show it here? And please do not use the comments section for posting code snippets as they cannot be formatted properly. Go ahead and edit your question.

Comment: Darin, ja-JP is just the parameter which is used to initialize the culture. it's not a script. i updated the question for more visibility on my problem